# Basic filtering in LINQ to XML Queries

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to XDocument and LINQ. Here is what I am trying to do :

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <chapters total-chapters="3">
    <Chapter chapter-no="1">
      <chapter-summary>this is chapter 1</chapter-summary>
    </Chapter>
    <Chapter chapter-no="2">
      <chapter-summary>this is chapter 2</chapter-summary>
    </Chapter>
    <Chapter chapter-no="3">
      <chapter-summary>this is chapter 3</chapter-summary>
    </Chapter>
    <Chapter chapter-no="4">
      <chapter-summary>this is chapter 4</chapter-summary>
    </Chapter>
</chapters>
</root>
```

Now I need to read all the records with a specific chapter-no. I am writing my LINQ query as :

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elem_list = 
    from e in xdoc.Elements("Chapter") 
    where (string) e.Attribute("chapter-no") == "1" 
    select e;

foreach (XElement e in elem_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

but elem_list is not getting populated and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Elements("Chapter")` search only within direct children of current element (root for `xdoc`).

You can use `.Descendants("Chapter")`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elem_list = from e in xdoc.Descendants("Chapter")
                                  where (string) e.Attribute("chapter-no") == "1"
                                  select e;
```

Or specify full item path:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elem_list = from e in xdoc.Root.Element("chapters").Elements("Chapter")
                                  where (string) e.Attribute("chapter-no") == "1"
                                  select e;
```

Another approach - with `XPath` selector:

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("root/chapters/Chapter[@chapter-no=1]");
```

`using System.Xml.XPath;` is necessary to make the last sample work.

Comment: XPath seems to be very helpful... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elem_list = 
   xdoc.Descendants("Chapter")
   .Where (c => c.Attribute("chapter-no").Value.Equals("1"));
```